# angularjs:Fixed header problems with anchors

Tags: html, css, angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have a fixed header in the top of my page and also I used anchors in angularjs. My problem is when I clicked `anchor 1` the div jump in the top of the page and I cannot see it. The `anchor` is behind of the fixed header which should not.

How can I fixed this one. Thanks in advance.
I am currently referring to this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZqAWjHZbTJCtlDL2qpu?p=preview

Comment: So what is the desired behavior when navigating?  If you scroll to the 3rd one, where should the previous two be?

Comment: I want the word `Anchor 1 of 5 ` and so forth to be outside of the fixed header.